# How can i add new line after specific pattern in string in java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Array list of strings

```
[1 Week, 2-4 Weeks, 4-8 weeks, 8-12 weeks, >12 weeks]
```

currently i'm returning string in the following way

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter((value, axis) -> {
        int val = (int) value;
        String formatString;
        if (val >= 0 && val < xList.length) {
            Log.e("xList[(int) value]",xList[(int) value]);
            formatString = xList[(int) value];
            return formatString;
        }
        return String.valueOf((int) value);
    });
```

in the above code formatString returns each string in arraylist but how to add '\n' after 2-4 ,4-8, 8-12,>12 patterns

Answer (score 2):

use string.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) and "\n" for new line